# java.lang.AssertionError during spring boot testing

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

i'am using spring boot for testing (i very new to Spring boot), i want to mock my Rest API script during testing phase so i'm using `MockRestServiceServer` to create a mock server.

now, whenever i run the `server.verify()` i always get this error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected leaving 1 unsatisfied expectation(s).
```

here is my main call method

```
    @Test
    public void call() {
        RestTemplate template = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(template);
        DataParser parser = Mockito.mock(DataParser.class);
        RTCValidate validate = Mockito.mock(RTCValidate.class);
        NodeExe nodeExe = Mockito.mock(NodeExe.class);
        RTCInterpreter interpreter = new RTCInterpreter(parser, validate, nodeExe);
        Mockito.when(parser.parse(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("2012-02-08");

        server.expect(requestTo("http://vpn.fakemood.com/certmgmt/L1ip?uuid={uuid}")).andRespond(withSuccess("123ABC456", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

        server.verify();
    }
```

i'm not sure why this error , the actual API works fine, so does the actual code. the URL is correct as well but then which expectation failed??

why do i get this error and what does it actually mean??

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You declared your `expect()` and after that you are calling `verify()`. `verify()` verifies that all expected requests set up via expect(RequestMatcher) were indeed performed.

Your code immediately call `verify()` after declaring your expectation. No implementation will do a call against the server.

Check this example, between `expect()` and `verify()` is some implementation that calls your excepted requests.

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()
 MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();

 server.expect(manyTimes(), requestTo("/hotels/42")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
     .andRespond(withSuccess("{ \"id\" : \"42\", \"name\" : \"Holiday Inn\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

 Hotel hotel = restTemplate.getForObject("/hotels/{id}", Hotel.class, 42);
 // Use the hotel instance...

 // Verify all expectations met
 server.verify();
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html

Comment: well it dint work when i called the method, it showed the same error so i removed it. adding it right now still shows the same error.